Trying to load C# file by MS visual studio but the default encoding is incorrect
I am using MS visual studio 2022 and today when I opened my C# project, the file default encoding seems incorrect:
click to see wrong encoding
I checked and found one solution here. I have set my "Language for non-Unicode programs" setting to "English (United States)" and unchecked the Beta settings:
click to see my setting
but this does not work for me. Then I changed my IDE from vs 2022 to vs 2019, and pulled my project from repo again, and then opened the completely new peoject, and all these methods does not work for me.
I found that I can use vs code to open the wrong encoded file with encoding gb-2312, and then save it with encoding utf-8, but my projects contains thousands of wrong encoded files, I even tried to write a python script, but it does not help:
import os

def convert_encoding(source_folder, target_encoding='utf-8'):
    # define files that I want to change encoding
    extensions = {'.cs', '.json'}

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
        for file in files:
            # get extensions
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
            # check 
            if ext.lower() in extensions:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                try:
                    # open with encoding gb2312
                    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                        contents = f.read().decode('gb2312')
                    
                    # save as utf-8
                    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding=target_encoding) as f:
                        f.write(contents)
                    print(f"Converted {file_path} to {target_encoding}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error converting {file_path}: {e}")

# set directory
source_folder = 'E:\\my\\project\\file\\dir'  
convert_encoding(source_folder)

May I know if anyone has encountered this weired situation? I appreciate if anyone could help me. Thank you!
For @Dai's suggestion: File > Open > File > (Find the file, but don't click the Open button yet; click the arrow in the Open button) > Open with Encoding, I am not if you are referring to this:
enter image description here
and I could not find utf-8 encoding, and I can only change the encoding one by one?
For @MarkRansom's suggestion, I opened file with utf-8 sig(click to see my setting), still has error encodings.

File > Open > File > (Find the file, but don't click the Open button yet; click the arrow in the Open button) > Open with Encoding

@Dai Hi, please look at my updated post. I could not find utf-8 encoding, and I can only change the encoding one by one

Try changing target_encoding from utf-8 to utf_8_sig.  Sometimes Microsoft products won't believe your files are UTF-8 unless you put a BOM on them.

Sorry, I meant "Open With..." > "Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding > UTF-8

Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

You face a mojibake case: '二维出图配置文件'.encode( 'gb2312').decode( 'cp1252') returns '¶þÎ¬³öÍ¼ÅäÖÃÎÄ¼þ'. (二维出图配置文件 meaning is Binary drawing configuration file by Google Translate).

I tried all methods including changing visual studio from 2022 to 2019, and I even reinstalled my windows system from scratch (removing all my data and set computer to factory settings) and none of these methods works! it made me insane :(
